# representing custom properties in string in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to represent some custom properties in a plain string like how we use properties in XML/JSON.

**Example:**

```
some_string1${object1.property1}some_string2${object2.property1}
```

This is what I am trying:

```
package com.foo.bar;

public class CustomStringFormator {
    public String formatString(String input) {
    String output = null;
    // Here I need solution to extract ${} patterns using regex and replace
    // the substitutions for that by calling getValueForProperty() method
    // example getValueForProperty("object1.property1") return value1
    return output;
}

private String getValueForProperty(String property) {
    String value = null;
    // some known logic
    return value;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String output = new CustomStringFormator()
            .formatString("some_string1_${object1.property1}_some_string2${object2.property1}");
    // output will be like 
    // some_string1_value1_some_string2_value2
}
}
```

I am using plain string instead of other text representation because I want to optimize this operation maximum.

In formatString method I want a solution to replace the `${property}` tokens with the value returned by the `getValueForProperty(property)`.

Please give me your suggestions.

Comment: What is you actual problem or question?

Comment: In formatString method I want solution to replace the ${property} tokens with the value returned by the getValueForProperty(property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public String formatString(String input) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{\\s*(\\w+\\.\\w+)\\s*\\}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while(matcher.find()){
        String key = matcher.group(1);
        String value = getValueForProperty(key);// object1.property1,object2.property1
        String output = input.replace(matcher.group(),value);
        input = output;
    }
    return output;
}
```